# Why is WebRTC peer.ontrack not being called in 1-1 peer connection?

Tags: javascript, networking, webrtc, p2p, live-streaming

I have a video call app where I a trying to create one to one peer connection.
But somehow track event is not getting dispatched despite  doing peer.addTrack from senders end.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Video App</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <h3>Your Id: <span id="myId"></span></h3>
        <h3>Online Users (click to connect)</h3>
        <div id="users">

        </div>
        <video id="local-video"></video>
        <video id="remote-video"></video>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p id="status"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Import socket.io script -->
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="./client.js"<</script>

</body>

</html>
```

client.js

```
const socket = io();

const peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302", "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478"],
    },
  ],
});

const createCall = async (to) => {
  const status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerText = `Calling ${to}`;

  const localOffer = await peer.createOffer();
  await peer.setLocalDescription(localOffer);

  socket.emit("outgoing:call", { fromOffer: localOffer, to });
};

peer.ontrack = async ({ streams: [stream] }) => {
  console.log("Incoming stream", stream);

  const status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerText = "Incomming Stream";

  const video = document.getElementById("remote-video");
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();

  const mySteam = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
  });

  for (const track of mySteam.getTracks()) {
    peer.addTrack(track, mySteam);
  }
};

socket.on("users:joined", (id) => {
  const usersDiv = document.getElementById("users");
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  const textNode = document.createTextNode(id);

  btn.id = id;

  btn.setAttribute("onclick", `createCall('${id}')`);
  btn.appendChild(textNode);
  usersDiv.appendChild(btn);
});

socket.on("incomming:answere", async (data) => {
  const status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerText = "incomming:answere";

  const { offer } = data;
  await peer.setRemoteDescription(offer);
});

socket.on("user:disconnect", (id) => {
  document.getElementById(id).remove();
});

socket.on("incomming:call", async (data) => {
  const status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerText = "incomming:call";

  const { from, offer } = data;

  await peer.setRemoteDescription(offer);

  const answereOffer = await peer.createAnswer();
  await peer.setLocalDescription(answereOffer);

  socket.emit("call:accepted", { answere: answereOffer, to: from });
  const mySteam = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
  });

  for (const track of mySteam.getTracks()) {
    peer.addTrack(track, mySteam);
  }
});

const getAndUpdateUsers = async () => {
  const usersDiv = document.getElementById("users");
  usersDiv.innerHTML = "";

  const response = await fetch("/users", { method: "GET" });
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();

  console.log(jsonResponse);

  jsonResponse.forEach((user) => {
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(user[0]);

    btn.id = user[0];

    btn.setAttribute("onclick", `createCall('${user[0]}')`);
    btn.appendChild(textNode);
    usersDiv.appendChild(btn);
  });
};

socket.on("hello", ({ id }) => (document.getElementById("myId").innerText = id));

const getUserMedia = async () => {
  const userMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
  });

  const videoEle = document.getElementById("local-video");
  videoEle.srcObject = userMedia;
  videoEle.play();
};

window.addEventListener("load", getAndUpdateUsers);
window.addEventListener("load", getUserMedia);
```

sever.js (Used to create the inital connection)

```
//import and initialization
const io = new SocketIO(server);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Create a users map to keep track of users
const users = new Map();

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(`user connected: ${socket.id}`);
    users.set(socket.id, socket.id);

    // emit that a new user has joined as soon as someone joins
    socket.broadcast.emit('users:joined', socket.id);
    socket.emit('hello', { id: socket.id });

    socket.on('outgoing:call', data => {
        const { fromOffer, to } = data;

        socket.to(to).emit('incomming:call', { from: socket.id, offer: fromOffer });
    });

    socket.on('call:accepted', data => {
        const { answere, to } = data;
        socket.to(to).emit('incomming:answere', { from: socket.id, offer: answere })
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`user disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
        users.delete(socket.id);
        socket.broadcast.emit('user:disconnect', socket.id);
    });
});


app.use(express.static( path.resolve('./public') ));

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    return res.json(Array.from(users));
});

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at PORT:${PORT}`));
```

There are no errors in console

peer.getReceivers() and peer.getSenders() both an empty array.